# Correct way to support a pipe run parallel to floor joists

Tags: plumbing, pipe, joists

I would like to install pipe parallel to the floor joists in my basement, and then conceal it behind drywall.

I need to do this with both gas (black iron) and domestic water (copper) pipe.

I'm tempted to use simple copper straps to affix the pipes to the joists themselves.  Is this code-compliant?  (The fact that this answer is so hard to find online suggests that it may be this simple.)

I've also seen pipes suspended between joists with a wood support--is it better to hang the pipe from a wooden support which is attached to the joist, to prevent rust from contact with the wood?  (I've seen this elsewhere in my 100-year-old house.)

What is the standard, code-compliant way to support a pipe run parallel to floor joists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally would cut blocking that fits between the joist.  Nail them in place flush with the bottom side of the joist about every 6'.  Now you have a nice flat surface to lay the piping on.  Then use and approved strap to eliminate noise.

Comment: I'm with you on the blocking idea, but to clarify: won't it be easier to attach to the *bottom* of blocking (i.e. having recessed it slightly into the joist bay)--or do you really hammer and/or screw in clamps on the top side of blocking?

Answer (score 2):

whichever way you support the pipes, both types of piping will expand and contract. (The copper will expand the most). When they do, they will make creaking noises that will be permanent if the space is covered with dry wall or any other finish product. Any pipe in contact with wood or any hard object will make noise so I would use only connectors, hangers, clamps, etc.  that have a rubber type insulator to keep the pipe from contact with any hard material. A pipe passing through a wooden item will also make noise so use caution and install a rubber sleeve, even if you have to make one yourself with flat rubber gasket material. And use products that are compatible with the type of metal you are supporting; (copper for copper and metal with metal).Only protection and prevention will stop the noise from happening. Hope this helps.

Comment: + for like material straps, copper to steel will be problematic, insulated or rubber on the hot water pipe is always a good way to quiet things down.